# fetching data from remote databases

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to make application on google app engine which can fetch data from my other remote database , as far as i have learned that we can do it by using python in this way , If i am not wrong 
import urllib

```
form_fields = {
  "first_name": "Albert",
  "last_name": "Johnson",
  "email_address": "Albert.Johnson@example.com"
}
form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_fields)
result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,
                        payload=form_data,
                        method=urlfetch.POST,
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Is is possible that i can fetch data from one of my [this](http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/androidjson.php?identifier=123) url using java and get the data store in  datastore . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to do it along those lines - is there a particular problem you're running into? Also, you may want to note that this means your remote database is exposed to the world, so you should have some means of protecting access to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concern , the code stated is in python so i was wondering is there any source which can guide to achieve in java for parsing json on google app engine

Comment: It shouldn't be any different than parsing JSON in general (e.g., nothing App Engine-specific) - I would think http://json.org/java/ would work fine as a reference.